# How do I remove duplicates from the MAXMIND database?

Tags: sql, duplicates, maxmind

I am currently working on the Maxmind database with the GeoIPCity-Location table and realised that hundreds of thousands of the data are duplicates. For example, I've searched for Newcastle Upon Tyne with:

```
SELECT * FROM MAXMIND
WHERE city='Newcastle Upon Tyne';
```

Which results in:

```
369137  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE20    54.9881 -1.6194
369332  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE6 54.9881 -1.6194
369345  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE13    54.9881 -1.6194
369355  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE3 54.9881 -1.6194
369356  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE5 54.9881 -1.6194
369645  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE4 54.9881 -1.6194
369706  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE15    54.9881 -1.6194
369959  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE12    54.9881 -1.6194
370114  GB  I7  Newcastle Upon Tyne NE27    54.9881 -1.6194
```

This is worse if I just search for "Newcastle":

```
382 ZA  2   Newcastle       -27.758 29.9318
2279    US  OK  Newcastle   73065   35.2323 -97.6008
26459   US  CA  Newcastle   95658   38.873  -121.1543
22382   CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1j9  43.9167 -78.5833
38995   AU  2   Newcastle       -32.9278    151.7845
40025   US  ME  Newcastle   4553    44.0438 -69.5675
47937   GB  I7  Newcastle       54.9881 -1.6194
119830  US  ME  Newcastle   4553    44.0438 -69.5675
119982  US  NE  Newcastle   68757   42.6475 -96.9232
115052  US  CA  Newcastle   95658   38.873  -121.1543
120603  US  NE  Newcastle   68757   42.6475 -96.9232
127931  US  OK  Newcastle   73065   35.2323 -97.6008
136726  CA  ON  Newcastle       43.9167 -78.5833
136915  US  TX  Newcastle   76372   33.245  -98.9103
137128  US  WY  Newcastle   82701   43.8396 -104.5681
137130  US  WY  Newcastle   82701   43.8396 -104.5681
144799  IE  16  Newcastle       52.4492 -9.0611
207626  US  UT  Newcastle   84756   37.6924 -113.6272
213128  US  UT  Newcastle   84756   37.6924 -113.6272
221968  KN  5   Newcastle       17.2    -62.5833
229237  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1l4  43.9167 -78.5833
232235  GB  M9  Newcastle       54.9881 -1.6194
229005  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1g1  43.9167 -78.5833
228722  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1k9  43.9167 -78.5833
242102  CA  NB  Newcastle       46.9833 -65.5667
252530  IE  7   Newcastle       53.3011 -6.5022
267662  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1h5  43.9167 -78.5833
266263  IE  31  Newcastle       53.0683 -6.0658
313271  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1h8  43.9167 -78.5833
306632  IE  10  Newcastle       53.3408 -8.6783
320151  CA  ON  Newcastle   l1b1l2  43.9167 -78.5833
336868  GB  L6  Newcastle       52.4333 -3.1167
353050  GB  R9  Newcastle       54.2    -5.8833
349314  GB  Q7  Newcastle       54.3833 -5.4667
377107  ZA  2   Newcastle   2940    -27.758 29.9318
369587  GB  I7  Newcastle   ST5 54.9881 -1.6194
387865  AU  2   Newcastle   2297    -32.9278    151.7845
387889  AU  2   Newcastle   2300    -32.9278    151.7845
387978  AU  2   Newcastle   2306    -32.9278    151.7845
388098  AU  2   Newcastle   2302    -32.9278    151.7845
392595  AU  2   Newcastle   2296    -32.9278    151.7845
388376  AU  2   Newcastle   2899    -32.9278    151.7845
```

Is there any way to remove the duplicates? How would I know which duplicate to remove and which ones to keep?

Thanks

Comment: The first dataset are complete duplicates. They are all same lat/lon and city name. Searching for a city name should give me 20 results of the same city with different postcodes.

Comment: You've completely missed the point.

Comment: I have missed the point?  In your first table you have records that are not duplicates.  First of all they all have a different PK in the first column.  Second, they have a column aside from the PK which Contains values like 'NE%' which also makes the rows unique.  If you want to return just a single result with the coordinates, you need to select distinct omitting those two fields.  

In your second table, with the PK aside you have confirmed duplicates.  Same logic applies however.  

If I am missing the point then I contend the question needs clarification.

Comment: So your two options with that data provided are to either use a select distinct, or use a group by on all your distinct columns.  

select city, postalCode, coordinates from maxmind where city = 'Newcastle Upon Tyne' group by city, postalcode, coordinates

or whatever your column names are. 

Or
select distinct city, postalcode, coordinates from maxmind